# How to process a test on WebDriver, when element is not present

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

I have a test to get a page. There is a large number of checkboxes on the page and the checkbox I'm looking for disappears by day.

Processing of my test will stop with the below error, if there is no such checkbox:

> ... (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchElementError) ...

I am writing the test as follows now:

```
driver.navigate.to 'http://test.com/' 
driver.find_element(:id, "checkbox1").click
```

I want the test to ignore these lines, when there is no checkbox on the page and only to try to click on it, when it is there.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby lets you write code like this:

`driver.find_element(:id, "checkbox1").click if driver.find_element(:id, "checkbox1").displayed`?

However, in this instance, the same error will occur because of the find_element in the "if".

However if you write a method or extend the WebDriver class, you could do something like this;

```
driver.find_element(:id, "checkbox1").click if element_displayed?(driver,id: =>"checkbox1")
```

there are lots of ways to approach this but you can get the idea

Comment: I wrote as follows, but it did not go well

driver.find_element(:id, "checkbox1").click if element_displayed?(driver,id: =>"checkbox1")


  def element_displayed?(how, what)
    driver.find_element(how, what)
    true
  rescue Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchElementError
    false
  end

Comment: Your constructors do not match

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve that, you'll have to use begin...rescue block like following:

```
begin
  driver.find_element(:id, "checkbox1").click
rescue Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchElementError
  # do nothing
end
```

In above code, if element is found it will be clicked. If it's not found, then it won't do anything; it will only catch the exception.